# Multiple input in single cell

Tags: mysql

I saw this question answered already, but in a different instance which then got some advice as well as the necessary information. The context for mine vs the other's is quite different I believe.

My ambition is to make a kind of dictionary which would contain 3 tables types:

**Table 1**: main dictionary which contains all of my entries

Contains the primary key integer; English word; Chinese word; topic (ie., Animals, food, etc - and this is where I want to have multiple entries for a single cell, since some words will be viable for multiple topics); part of speech (verb, noun, etc); determiner boolean; determiner (if boolean is true it would contain a string, if false it would have a null value); date added; difficulty rating

**Table 2 (group)**: Each topic would have its own table according to the topic: Animals, food, measuring, etc.

This table would include a counting integer or table key; English word; Chinese word; the part of speech it belongs to; a counter (how many times it's used in my application).

**Table 3 (group)**: Parts of Speech Tables. Each table would be named after its particular branch of speech. nounProper, nounCommon, actionVerb, etc.

Would contain an integer key; English word; Chinese word

The purpose of this database is to feed a sentence generating program that can have vocabulary and topic tables added as I progress. Should I, in table 1, make multiple entries in cells when they span multiple topics, or should I leave that out altogether and simply assemble the table in a query rather than in the db table itself?

Comment: Learn about database normalization. Multiple entries in a single cell is a violation of normalization rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try a schema, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id`         serial PRIMARY KEY,
  `english`    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `chinese`    varchar(255) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
  `determiner` varchar(255),
  `added`      date NOT NULL,
  `difficulty` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `id`    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  `topic` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `word_topics` (
  `word_id`  integer,
  `topic_id` integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`, `topic_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`word_id`) REFERENCES `words`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`topics_id`) REFERENCES `topics`(`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `parts_of_speech` (
  `id`             serial PRIMARY KEY,
  `part_of_speech` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `word_pos` (
  `word_id` integer,
  `pos_id`  integer,
  PRIMARY KEY (`word_id`, `pos_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`word_id`) REFERENCES `words`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`pos_id`) REFERENCES `parts_of_speech`(`id`)
);
```

And queries like this one:

```
SELECT `w`.*, `topic`, `part_of_speech`
FROM `words` AS `w`
LEFT JOIN `word_topics` AS `wt` ON `w`.`id` = `wt`.`word_id`
LEFT JOIN `topics` AS `t` ON `t`.`id` = `wt`.`topic_id`
LEFT JOIN `word_pos` AS `wp` ON `w`.`id` = `wp`.`word_id`
LEFT JOIN `parts_of_speech` AS `p` ON `t`.`id` = `wp`.`pos_id`
```

### Edited above as well...

To get a random word by topic:

```
SELECT `w`.*, `topic`, `part_of_speech`
FROM `words` AS `w`
LEFT JOIN `word_topics` AS `wt` ON `w`.`id` = `wt`.`word_id`
LEFT JOIN `topics` AS `t` ON `t`.`id` = `wt`.`topic_id`
LEFT JOIN `word_pos` AS `wp` ON `w`.`id` = `wp`.`word_id`
LEFT JOIN `parts_of_speech` AS `p` ON `t`.`id` = `wp`.`pos_id`
WHERE `wt`.`topic_id` = ?
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```

You could also (replace or) add other conditions to the `WHERE` clause, using the `AND`/`OR` keywords...

Comment: OK, so parts of what you wrote certainly look usable. I am using SQLiteStudio, and I looked for a way to add "CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" to the schema, but was unable to see a way to do that. Should I edit the schema in a text editor? Am I missing something in the SQLiteStudio client?

The other issue is that I need to have a table for each topic. The reason is that I will need to make a random method which would get a number between 1 ~ .length(). So, the key (in a given topic table) would contain integers which would allow me to do that.

Comment: You tagged your question with `MySQL`, now you wrote you use `SQLite`... My answer was using `MySQL` syntax, especially the `CHARACTER SET` part...